# ASP.net upload file, rename if exists

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote this:

```
protected void btnup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ASPxUploadControl1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(ASPxUploadControl1.FileName);
            ASPxUploadControl1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("upload/") + filename);
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, if I already have File1.jpg, it will overwrite it if someone else uploads File1.jpg.

What to do here?

Comment: what is the real problem ? can you check if FileExist ? first or you can not connect the user with the files ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here what you can do to make the file name unique on server to avoid overwrites.

```
if (ASPxUploadControl1.HasFile)
{
    try
    {
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(ASPxUploadControl1.FileName);
        string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string fileLocation = string.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", 
                                            Server.MapPath("upload/"), 
                                            id, extension);
        ASPxUploadControl1.SaveAs( fileLocation );
        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. " 
                            + "The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

when you call `ASPxUploadControl1.SaveAs`, assign is a unique name. for example, a running number / GUID / MD5 hash of the contents. whatever you may see fit.

I find it is easiest to create a new GUID string using: `System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to give the file name a `unique` name.
A DB-sequence or a static running number variable might fit you.

You can use a random unique GUID string, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) MSDN article

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use a Guid when you save files in web applications to avoid this problems, I usually use:

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "").ToUpper()
```

for the file name.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void btnup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ASPxUploadControl1.HasFile)
            {
                try
                {
                    string ext = Path.GetExtension(ASPxUploadControl1.FileName);
                    string filename = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()+ext;
                    ASPxUploadControl1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("upload/") + filename);
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
                }
            }
    }
```